# Tempfile and Garbage Collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, garbage-collection

I have this command in a Rails controller

```
  open(source) { |s| content = s.read }
  rss = RSS::Parser.parse(content, false)
```

and it is resulting in temporary files that are filling up the (scarce) disk space.

I have examined the problem to some extent and it turns out somewhere in the stack this happens:

```
io = Tempfile.new('open-uri')
```

but it looks like this Tempfile instance never gets explicitly closed. It's got a

```
def _close  # :nodoc:
```

method which might fire automatically upon garbage collection?

Any help in knowing what's happening or how to clean up the tempfiles would be helpful indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like `_close` closes the file and then waits for garbage collection to unlink (remove) the file. Theoretically you could force unlinking immediately by calling the `Tempfile`'s `close!` method instead of `close`, or to call `close(true)` (which calls `close!` internally).

*edit:* But the problem is in open-uri, which is out of your hands - and that makes no promises for cleaning up after itself: it just assumes that the garbage collector will finalize all `Tempfile`s in due time.

In such a case, you are left with no choice but to call the garbage collector yourself using `ObjectSpace.garbage_collect` ([see here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/ObjectSpace.html#M006759)). This should cause the removal of all temp files.

Comment: so who calls _close? Without monkey patching I have no access to that tempfile, I think.

Comment: I see the problem now. I added some more info to the answer, hopefully  it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for that! I cannot imagine that calling the GC explicitly will resolve the problem. In my testing, the only way to get a tempfile to NOT get cleaned up is to interrupt the program. So I can't figure out what might be happening.

Comment: I think its a bug in `open-uri` (maybe not a bug per-se, but definitely mis-behavior) that it does not clean up temp files properly. That being said - it passes the buffers around so much that its hard to figure out where to close the Tempfile. I do believe that a lot of refactoring can solve the problem in `open-uri` but that would have to wait for another time :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to force `open-uri` not to use a tempfile, you can mess with the `OpenURI::Buffer::StringMax` constant:

```
> require 'open-uri'
=> true 
> OpenURI::Buffer::StringMax
=> 10240 
> open("http://www.yahoo.com")
=> #<File:/tmp/open-uri20110111-16395-8vco29-0> 
> OpenURI::Buffer::StringMax = 1_000_000_000_000
(irb):10: warning: already initialized constant StringMax
=> 1000000000000 
> open("http://www.yahoo.com")
=> #<StringIO:0x6f5b1c>
```

That's because of this snippet from `open-uri.rb`:

```
class Buffer
  [...]
  StringMax = 10240
  def <<(str)
    [...]
    if [...] StringMax < @size
      require 'tempfile'
```

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not a bug, but faulty error handling the IO.  Buffer.io is either StringIO if the @size is less than 10240 bytes or a Tempfile if over that amount.  The ensure clause in OpenURI.open_uri() is calling close(), but because it could be a StringIO object, which doesn't have a close!() method, it just can't just call close!().

The fix, I think, would be either one of these:

The ensure clause checks for class and calls either StringIO.close or Tempfile.close! as needed.

--or--

The Buffer class needs a finalizer that handles the class check and calls the correct method.

Granted, neither of those fix it if you don't use a block to handle the IO, but I suppose in that case, you can do your own checking, since open() returns the IO object, not the Buffer object.

The lib is a big chunk of messy code, imho, so it could use a work-over to clean it up. I think I might do that, just for fun. ^.^

Comment: SynTruth, I get the idea, but in a duck-typing language, you don't check the class. You check whether it responds to a method :). Anyway, I am so far from this problem now that I wouldn't know if you fixed it. But report back if you do, just for curiosity's sake.